# Текст над кругом в теге span

Tags: html, css

Как текст внутри тега `span` разместить над кругом по центру?

```css
.step__point {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.point {
  min-width: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: background 1s ease;
}

.pre-line,
.post-line {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  margin-top: 18px;
  transition: background 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="step__point">
  <div class="pre-line"></div>
  <span class="point">1</span>
  <div class="post-line"></div>
  <div class="pre-line"></div>
  <span class="point">2</span>
  <div class="post-line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно через `position: relative` и `top: xxx` сделать:

```css
.step__point {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.pre-line,
.post-line {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  margin-top: 18px;
  transition: background 1s ease;
}

.point {
  display:  inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;

  min-width: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;

  text-align: center;
}

.point:after {
  content: '';

  display:  inline-block;

  position: relative;
  top: 5px;

  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;

  border-radius: 18px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  transition: background 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="step__point">
  <div class="pre-line"></div>
  <div class="point">1</div>
  <div class="post-line"></div>
  <div class="pre-line"></div>
  <div class="point">2</div>
  <div class="post-line"></div>
</div>
```

Но я бы полностью переделал сам подход на более простой

1. контейнер с вертикальной границей
2. поверх контейнера через `flex` объекты содержащие круг и текст - как это сделать уже на любителя - я, как в примере, через `:after` круг рисовал, но можно внутри контейнера с кругом еще контейнер с текстом разместить - хотя конечно тогда тегов больше будет :)

P.S.

на самом деле даже `pre-line` и `post-line` не нужны - это все можно сделать через `:before` и `:after`

Comment: а как через :before и :after линию сделать горизонтальную вместо pre-line и post-line

Comment: через :before рисуете прямоугольник с одной горизонтальной границей, через :after круг по центу и через основной тег число, но можно сделать так - рисовать через :after круг, через основной тег цифру, а горизонтальную линию рисовать через родителя - это будет еще проще, вам же надо равномерно круги разбросать - так ведь?

Comment: да, равномерно нужно

Answer (score 4):

еще один вариант как сделать данную задачу с минимальным кол-вом тегов:

```css
.step__point {
  display:          flex;
  justify-content:  space-around;

  height:           36px;

  margin-top:       50px;
  
  border-bottom:    2px solid #E0E0E0;
  transition:       background 1s ease;
}

.point, .point:after {
  display:          inline-block;

  min-width:        36px;
  width:            36px;
  height:           36px;

  text-align:       center;
}

.point:after {
  content:          '';

  border-radius:    18px;
  border:           2px solid #ffffff;
  
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  transition:       background 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="step__point">
  <div class="point">1</div>
  <div class="point">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант заключить циферки в отдельный `span`

```css
.step__point {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.point {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: background 1s ease;
}

.point>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -18px;
  min-width: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pre-line,
.post-line {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  margin-top: 18px;
  transition: background 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="step__point">
  <div class="pre-line"></div>
  <span class="point"><span>1</span></span>
  <div class="post-line"></div>
  <div class="pre-line"></div>
  <span class="point"><span>2</span></span>
  <div class="post-line"></div>
</div>
```